# putting file on blackberry emulator file system

Tags: file, blackberry, system, simulator

I need to put a video file on the file system of the Blackberry emulator to test the app I'm writing.  I can't figure out how to do this.  How can I copy a file from my computer's file system onto the simulator's file system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Eclipse or the JDE you can edit the properties for the simulator - one of those properties is to simulate an SD card.  If you turn on this option, you can point to a directory on your hard drive and have it show up in the simulator as an SD card, including all of the files in that directory.

Comment: Thanks very much - that was it.  In my simulator, it was a "Change SD Card" menu item in the "Simulator" menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can also comfortable access the storage via FTP, more details here:
https://developer.blackberry.com/develop/simulator/simulator_configuring.html